# Jquery scrolling image not working in IE

Tags: jquery

Simply put, I want an image to move up and down and not left and right.
I found this bit of jquery and changed it to help myself and it works in chrome and firefox, but Lord help me with IE (like always).

Trying to make it to this: http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/
the middle one.  Works in chrome and ffox just not IE 9

```
    /*js*/
$(document).scroll(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$(".natface").css('left', 114 - $this.scrollLeft());
});

/*css */
.natface{
position: fixed;
left: 114px;
width: 88px;
height: 93px;
z-index: -2;
}
```

This allows me to scroll up and down the page and have this image travel up and down, but when I make a window smaller and then scroll left to right, this makes it to where it won't scroll right and left.  This isn't the case in IE sadly as even if I make the window smaller it still scrolls to the right when I scroll right.

If you can image a margin line box with an image that scrolls down the left side of it slightly over lapping it to look as if it's speaking into the text box.  That is my intention.

I'm very new to all this as well so it's kinda of tough to know where I'm going wrong.  Sorry first time jusing stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You totally changed the question and now I'm a bit confused. I think your problem with position fixed and IE might be because you're running in quirksmode. You need a `strict` doctype for position:fixed to work in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Leaving my old answer in here too:

There's the CSS property `position:fixed`, but this property isn't supported on IE6 and iOS 4 I think.

**position:fixed JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/DLeYv/1/

If you wanna use Javascript, something like this would make it scroll both horizontally and vertically:

```
$(".natface")
  .css('top', 114 + $this.scrollTop())
  .css('left', 100 + $this.scrollLeft());
```

This tells anything with the class `.natface` to scroll to the same amount of pixels as the window is scrolled (`scrollTop`) and then another 114 pixels down, and the same amount as scrolled left.

For this to work the .natface element needs to have a position of "absolute" and not be inside any other positioned elements (as in directly inside the `<body>` tag).

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/DUnUm/2/

Comment: I tried what you said, but now this oddly only scrolls up and down if I scroll from left to right (confusing) and does not scroll up and down with my page as I scroll down or up.

Comment: Try the Fiddle link, does it work as expected for you? Only tried it in Chrome but should work in IE too.

Comment: oh that works wonderfully, but I wouldn't know if the text that scrolls down the page is capable of moving from left to right if I were to make the window smaller and then move it to the right.

Comment: I accidentally put position relative when I originally had Fixed.  Darn Why does IE have to be so complicated. lol Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: If you were using position:fixed and it didn't work in IE it was probably because you were running in quirksmode. See my updated answer.

Comment: HOLY MOLLY It had nothing to do with jquery then.  Ok you are the man. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked! Disabling quirksmode tells IE to render HTML as standards-compliant as possible, so it looks more the same across different browsers. For example it also changes the box-model (how width and padding is calculated), so if you've already positioned elements in CSS using IE as your reference you'll have to redo them. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html